# Insert single row taking an hour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently looking into an issue on one of our SQL 2008 databases where it keeps appearing to lock up. It will be running fine for hours, then suddenly all our applications using that database will stop working. It's been happening for about 2 weeks now, before that there were no issues. Nothing much has changed in that time, certainly nothing that should cause this issue.

I've had SQL Profiler running to try and figure out what is going on. It shows hundreds of queries running every second throughout the day no problem at all, then suddenly there is a 10 minute gap where only a few queries have run. When looking around that time, I found an insert query that had been running for just over an hour. That same query (but different data) has been seen to have a lock on the database on several occasions when everything has frozen up.

Usually what we have to do to get it running is restart the sql server service, obviously that gets rid of any locks and kills any queries, and everything goes again. However it then stops again, sometimes within the hour, other times several hours later.

It's a simple insert which basically just says "insert into table (x, y, z) select x, y, x from sourcetable". When I run the select part of the statement that took an hour, it takes no time to run (literally it says 00:00:00), so I can't quite understand what is going on.

We did get a few errors coming up for a while saying that one of the tables may be corrupt(not the destination or source of the insert statement though). We ran the DBCC command on that table but it didn't report any errors.

I'm going to have a look at our .net application that is running that statement to see if there is anything there that is causing it, but its unlikely and wondering if anyone has seen anything like this before and knows what might be the cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possibly a dead-lock of that script in conjunction with another one?  Also, does the table have any triggers or something out of the ordinary attached to it?

Comment: Sounds like deadlock. Have you tried running `sp_lock` when this occurs?

Comment: We do get errors through occasionally about deadlocks, telling us that a query has been the victim of a deadlock, but thats been going on for a long time as far as I know, without the entire database locking up.

Comment: I will try sp_lock next time it happens and see if it helps, thanks.

Comment: Locks sound like a likely place to look; another thing could be a stored proc with dodgy transaction management (e.g. starting a transaction but never either committing it or rolling it back); it's also possible that backups or virus scanning are tying up the server.

Comment: I did wonder about backups, but as it fails at various times during the day I don't think this would be an issue. On occasions it doesn't actually completely freeze, the system just runs very slowly, however when looking at the resource usage on the server at that time its running normally, with no virus scanner taking resources.

Comment: Is the database set to autogrow, and is it already large/are the disks highly fragmented?

Comment: Maybe one of your drives is failing? Have you checked the system logs?

Comment: The database is set to autogrow by 10% unrestricted.

Comment: The event logs don't show anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

The server will tell you why it's waiting if you ask it the right questions.  Take a look at sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks for the session_id that's hanging and see what it's waiting on.  That might give you some insight into what's going on.

Comment: Excellent, sounds like that might tell us something useful.

As is always the way, it hasn't happened again yet since I posted my message so just waiting to see if it happens again.

Is it wrong to be hoping something goes wrong ASAP? :)

Comment: Also I would download sp_WhoIsActive by Adam Machanic and run that during the times that this query goes south. He has put a lot of work into the tool. You can pull more information than just looking at the raw output from the DMVs. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/12/03/who-is-active-v9-57-fast-comprehensive-dmv-collection.aspx

Comment: Thanks Quantum Elf, will give that a go when it freezes again.

Comment: It did actually freeze a couple of minutes ago, and I ran sp_lock. There are 2 rows in "WAIT" status, with a mode of "IX", both for the same table. When it freezes, a colleague looks at the activity monitor, and myself at the profiler, and it always seems to be on the same  INSERT statement. Although its actually inserting into a different table to the one that is in WAIT status, they are linked by keys, and so it does appear to be something to do with that table. 

Its also the table that another colleague has had corruption messages for, though running DBCC on it returns no errors.

Comment: It froze again a few minutes ago, so I ran the sp_WhoIsActive query. 

It showed up 8 locks, one of them suspended. 7 of those, and 2 other queries, had wait_info set to "LCK_M_IX". 

One thing that stands out in particular is the first lock in the list, which turns out is actually a scheduled job that runs every hour. On this occasion there were 463,463,096 reads, which seems rather high. The query took 11 minutes to run, on average its 2 milliseconds. So it looks promising that this might be the cause of the issue.